# Adding a nvarchar column with a variable size

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to dynamically add a column of an unknown size to a table. Why does the following not work or else how can I get the thing in the context to work?

```
DECLARE @size int
SET @size = 200
GO

ALTER TABLE Testbench.dbo.Certificate 
    ADD E35 NVARCHAR(@size)
```

This yields:

> Wrong syntax near `@size`

Context

```
DECLARE @size int
SET @size = 200
GO

ALTER TABLE Testbench.dbo.Certificate 
    ADD E35 NVARCHAR(@size)
GO

UPDATE Testbench.dbo.Certificate 
SET E35 = ''

ALTER TABLE Testbench.dbo.Certificate 
    ALTER COLUMN E35 NVARCHAR(@size) NOT NULL
```

This yields twice:

> Wrong syntax near `@size`

Thank you.

Comment: @loan . . . Does the first really work?

Comment: @GordonLinoff He isn't saying the first one works. The second statement is just showing the larger context that the broken part is in.

Comment: Both won't works

Comment: `alter table` and `alter column` do not support dynamic sizes this way. You will have to do this through dynamic sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the following not work?

Because you can't parameterize Data Definition Language (DDL) statements in SQL Server.  You can use Dynamic SQL instead.  EG:

```
DECLARE @size int
SET @size = 200
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = concat('ALTER TABLE Testbench.dbo.Certificate ADD E35 NVARCHAR(',@size,')')
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: (+1) Not, of course, that it is wise to do so. There can only be so many columns in a table, and the columns can only be so wide, because <insert overlong discussion about the perils of row overflows here>. Be certain that this is what you want and need to do, and that it won't cause serious future problems!

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

1. The first is the `GO` batch separator. `GO` is **not part of the sql language**. It's a batch separator used by several prominent tools, but it's not part of the language proper. What you're seeing is your tool sending the additional statements after each `GO` as part of separate sessions, where the `@size` variable no longer exists.
2. You can't use parameters in an `ALTER` statement anyway.